# how to find current loaded viewcontroller?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, detailview

I have an tabBarController app with 2 tabBarItems.
each viewControllers contains tableView.
On didSelectRowAtIndexPath i am loading the detailview with this lines of code:

```
detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController_iPad" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

detailViewController.selectedDetail = [selectedDetail valueForKey:@"cardText"];
detailViewController.selectedCardTitle2 = [selectedCardTitle valueForKey:@"cardTitle"];
detailViewController.selectedRow2 = [self.tableViewInbox indexPathForSelectedRow];
detailViewController.detailCardsArray = allCards;
detailViewController.detailAllFetchedCards = allFetchedCards;

detailViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[inboxViewController presentModalViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

Problem is, when detailView is loaded(is the actual shown viewController) and i change to the other tabBarItem, the detailView **DOES NOT DISMISS**. That means, that i cant load the detailView again, if didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called.

In my AppDelegate i have the method

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController  didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
```

In this method i will check up, if the detailView is the actual shown viewController.
And if it is, and the tabBarItem changes, THEN dismiss the DetailView.

**Now my question is: How can I CHECK, if the detailView is loaded (current shown view) or not?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html) tells us that the detailView becomes a child of the presenting view. The presenting view controller will have it's `modalViewController` property updated to point to the presented view. Also, the modal view's `parentViewController` will be updated to point to the presenting view.

So, you could check these properties to see whether or not the modal view is displayed or not.